# Where is the mistake in this flux calculation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

Consider a charge, $q$, which emits an electric field given by $$\mathbf{E}=\frac{kq}{r^2}\mathbf{u_r}.$$ Consider a circular loop of radius $R$ and choose a coordinate system such that the center $O$ of the loop is the origin, and the loop's axis of rotation coincides with the x-axis. A charge $q$ is at a distance $x$ from $O$ along the x-axis, and we would like to calculate the electric flux through the area enclosed by the loop.

It seems like a pretty simple calculation: Integrate the flux across the loop by shell integration. The infinitesimal flux across an annulus of thickness $dr$ and inner radius $r$ is $$d\Phi=(2 \pi r dr)E(r)\sin(\theta)$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the field and the plane of the loop, and $E(r)$ is the field strength at a point on the loop a distance $r$ from the center.

By geometry we have $\sin(\theta)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}$. Also $E(r)=\frac{kq}{x^2+r^2}$.

Hence

$$d\Phi=\frac{\pi kqxr}{(x^2+r^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.$$

Integrating over all the shells (annuli) as $r$ ranges between $0$ and $R$, we get

$$\Phi=\int_{o}^{R}d\Phi=\int_{o}^{R} \frac{\pi kqxr}{(x^2+r^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dr.$$

If I calculated the integral correctly, I get

$$\Phi=2\pi kq(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}})$$

So the flux goes to zero as $R$ goes to zero (the area becomes smaller) and as $x$ goes to infinity (the field becomes weaker), as expected. The only problem is if $x=0$, the above expression gives a nonzero value for the flux, which makes no sense, since the field is radial and thus if the charge is placed at the center of the loop, the flux through the loop should be zero.

I'm not sure where I went wrong?

Comment: Why would this be marked as off-topic? Seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me, with effort clearly shown ( in fact the whole solution is presented, and my question basically asks why the mathematical result seems to disagree with intuition)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did nothing wrong.

The total flux from the charge is $4\pi kq$ and in the limit of x tending to zero, half of the flux (a hemisphere) will pass through the loop which is the answer that you are getting.

Now if you go exactly zero, your $d\Phi=(2 \pi r dr)E(r)\sin(\theta)$ equation does not hold. So there's some sort of discontinuity here - the same kind we face when a charge is just inside or just outside the volume through which the flux is to be calculated.

Comment: Ah I see. So there is a real discontinuity. Thanks that makes a lot of sense, especially the reasoning with the hemisphere to verify that the limit of the flux as $x$ goes to zero gives the right answer.